# correction with lucene elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, error-correction

I'm a newbie in `Lucene Elasticsearch`. I don't know how to deal with it. In documentation, I didn't found what I'm looking for.

- I do have  a text and it contains some misspelling wrong words that I want to correct via  a large database containing correct words.
- As I do have a big database, I thought about `Lucene Slasticsearch` for the quick research in the database.

**Question**

I know we use `Lucene Slasticsearch` for search and indexation but I don't know if we can do a research with a wrong word and it returns the correct words which are "similar" of the wrong one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could mention how are you defining a word to be similar, for example just based on spelling or phonetically.

Assuming you want to do just a spelling-based correction, the best approach is using custom analyzers, and Elasticsearch has a whole bunch of options for that.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

What you need to do is:

1. First decide on what type of filter and tokenizer you want to use.
2. Then add the analyzer in your index settings.
3. Then add the analyzer in your mapping.